# Jolt to remove null elements of root elements

Tags: json, jolt

I need help to remove null elements from JSON using jolt. I want to remove only root level elements containing ***null***.

**Input** :

```json
{
  "x": null,
  "y": null,
  "z": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "2",
      "price": null,
      "quantity": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

**Expected Output**

```json
{
  "z": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "2",
      "price": null,
      "quantity": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the value of the `z` and bring in the `z` like this:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@z": "z"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just dive one level deeper while using basic **`"*": "&"`** match in order the attributes stated at the outermost level with ***null*** values to vanish such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&1[]" // &1 represents the key grabbed from one outer level(it's "z" here)
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]